# javascript closure to remember initial state

Tags: javascript

I have a div in CSS that works like this: SomeDiv has another class, that's sometimes SomeRedDiv and other times SomeBlueDiv. When I mouseenter on SomeDiv, I want it to add the class SomeYellowDiv. But when I mouseleave, I want it each div to return to its initial state, either SomeRedDiv or SomeBlueDiv. This is what I have:

```
     <div class="SomeDiv SomeRedDiv"></div>
     <div class="SomeDiv SomeBlueDiv"></div>

    $('.SomeDiv').mouseenter(function () {

       // this makes all SomeDivs turn yellow
       $(this).removeClass().addClass('SomeDiv SomeYellowDiv');
    });

    $('.SomeDiv').mouseleave(function () {

       // here I want to use closure so that the function remembers
       // which class it initially was; SomeBlueDiv or SomeRedDiv
       $('this).removeClass().addClass('SomeDiv'); // add the initial color class
    });
```

I could do this with a global but I want to see if a closure would make my code better; I know the concept of closure that allows functions to remember their state but I'm not sure how to make it work here.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clsoures don't apply here, since you have two unrelated functions.

Instead, you should use `$(this).data(...)`, which stores arbitrary data associated with an element.

Comment: You could write your own implementation using closures and possibly attaching them to the object; but jquery's .data() is already available.

Comment: What if I combined the two functions with some sort of call back? Would this be where closures come in?

Comment: @frenchie: You could put them both in a `.each()` call and declare a local variable in the outer function.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real need for closures here - you just need to push the red/blue class into some other data container on mouse enter, then reinstate it on mouse leave.

```
$('.SomeDiv').mouseenter(function () {
    //remember the current colour class...
    $(this).data('orig-colour', $(this).is('.SomeDivBlue') ? 'Blue' : 'Red'));
    //...and now remove it and add yellow
    $(this).removeClass('SomeDivRed SomeDivBlue').addClass('SomeYellowDiv');
});

$('.SomeDiv').mouseleave(function () {
    //remove yellow and reinstate the original colour class
    $(this).removeClass('SomeDivYellow').addClass('SomeDiv'+$(this).data('orig-colour'));
});
```

Note also I remove only the classes that need to be removed, as opposed to your code where you were removing all classes then re-adding as required.

You might also want to think about delegating the event if you have a lot of divs as this is more optimal performance wise. This isn't a big change;

```
$('.SomeDiv').mouseenter(...
```

becomes something like

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.SomeDiv', ...
```

Finally, I assume there is some programmatical reason as to why you physically need to remove a class. If the purpose is purely visual, at the risk of pointing out the obvious, you should craft your CSS so the yellow class merely overrides the effects of the blue/red class, alleviating the need to explicitly remove the latter.

Comment: Hmm, accepted then unaccepted. Not sure why - does what the OP asked.